# Where to set the focus in wizard pages?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface

I have a `Wizard` containing two wizard pages (`org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardPage`) and would like to set the focus for each page separately so that always the top input field of each page is focused.

Setting the focus in `WizardPage.createControl(Composite)`, the first page focus is set correctly. The second page does not have a focus.
This is due to `Wizard.createPageControls(Composite)` which creates all the pages at the beginning.

Where would be the place to handle the focus after switched to the next wizard page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override the `WizardPage` `setVisible` method and set focus when the page becomes visible:

```
@Override
public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
    super.setVisible(visible);

    if (visible) {
       // TODO set focus
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, I'll use that. Just for the record, make sure `super.setVisible(visible)` is called, which handles the visibility of the `control`.

Comment: Yes, added super call to answer

Answer (score 1):

JFace wizards don't offer a designated hook to set the focus. However, as [Greg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2670892/greg-449) already mentioned, the `setVisible()` method can be used to set the initial focus of a wizard page.

Usually, the focus of wizard pages should only be set when showing the page for the first time. If a user returns back to a page, the focus should remain where it was when the page was left.

Therefore, I usually guard the focus code so that it is only executed when the page is shown for the first time:

```java
private boolean firstTimeShown = true;

@Override
public void setVisible( boolean visible ) {
  super.setVisible( visible );
  if( visible && firstTimeShown ) {
    firstTimeShown = False;
    control.setFocus();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rüdiger. Just for the record, make sure `super.setVisible(visible)` is called, which handles the visibility of the `control`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I added the super call to the answer.